# Problems with the oputput in the console, C#

Tags: c#

I'm learning to program in C# and I'm having problems with the console, when I run the code below the console show the output but immediately close the window and I can't see anything. I don't know what to do to keep the window open. Any suggestion? I'll be very grateful.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace testApp_1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            String word = "Hello world!";

            Console.WriteLine(word);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: add  `Console.Readline()`

Comment: `Console.ReadKey(false);`

Comment: Press `Crtl` + `F5`. The console window will not close until you press any key.

Answer (score 2):

This happens because when you reach the last line, you also reach the end of the program, thus it terminates. To keep the console window open, just add
`Console.ReadKey()` as the last line.

Answer (score 2):

The execution continues after writing to the console and then the program exits. you need to do something to pause the execution, usually you would read something from the console:

```
Console.ReadKey();
```

to pause until the user presses a key

so your whole program might look like:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace testApp_1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            String word = "Hello world!";

            Console.WriteLine(word);

            //if you want the user to exit with any key press do this
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
            Console.ReadKey();

            //if you want the user to hit 'enter' to exit do this
            Console.WriteLine("Press enter to exit.");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

you can read about [Console.ReadKey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readkey.aspx) and [Console.ReadLine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readline.aspx) on MSDN

Answer (score 1):

Your code closes immediately, because it doesn't have anything else to do. What you'll want to do is to add this to the bottom of your code:

```
Console.Readline();
```

That will cause it to wait until you press Enter.

Answer (score 0):

If you hit ctrl + F5 ( run without debugging) it will not close. But if you run with debugging, it will close after execution.
You can use `Console.ReadLine();` in the end to wait for the user to hit return.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace testApp_1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            String word = "Hello world!";

            Console.WriteLine(word);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following method to read some user input: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.console.readline%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

But you *have to* do some input.

You can also use logger frameworks: log4net:
http://logging.apache.org/log4net/

Answer (score 0):

Console.ReadLine() is missing.